# Concerning the values on the boundary and the value in a open set

Tags: complex-analysis

I bring up this question because in many reference books this result is always directly used without any explanation, which might be kind of confusing for a beginner.

If we assume |f(z)| $\lt$ M in an arbitrary disk D, if f analytic, then |f| $\le$ M on $\partial D$. This stems from the continuity.

Now, 1. is this statement correct?

In other words, if we know a bound for the interior points, we also know this can be a bound for values on the boundary. (provided f analytic in a region including the disk)

2.When we took the region to be the maximum region that f can be analytic, I thought this statement no longer holds since then there must be a pole on the boundary, which causes trouble in every sense.

Comment: If there is pole on boundary the function cannot be bounded in the domain so the result still holds though in a less interesting way; on the other hand the function may not be continuable without a pole if singularity is not isolated (think of $\sum z^{2^n}/n^2$ which is bounded in the unit disc, continuous on boundary but not continuable anywhere on the unit circle; maximum modulus still applies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the statement is correct. If $|f(z_0)|>M$ for some $z_0\in\partial D$, then there is some $\delta>0$ such that $|z-z_0|<\delta\implies|f(z)-f(z_0)|>|f(z_0)|-M\implies|f(z)|>M$. And the disk $D(z_0,\delta)$ contains points of $D$.